# Next.js with Convertkit api Catching error on POST method (an unexpected error occurred)

Tags: javascript, post, next.js

I'm working on convert kit API with nextjs to integrate my app, from jsx I'm sending request as email. but I can't figure it out where the error is. When submitting the form I'm getting an Unexpected error occurred from the Catch block.

```
'use client'

import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function Hero() {
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors, formState } = useForm();
    const [serverMessage, setServerMessage] = useState(null);

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        setServerMessage(null);
        console.log(data.email)
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/subscribe`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });
            
            const responseData = await response.json();

            if (responseData.error) {
                setServerMessage(responseData.error);
            } else {
                setServerMessage('Thanks for subscribing!');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setServerMessage('An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.');
        }
    };
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-[#121212] px-4 mt-[-8]">
    <h1 className="text-[#EAEAEA] text-4xl md:text-5xl font-bold mb-3 md:mb-4 text-center w-full md:w-[500px]">
        Unlock the Secrets of SaaS Success
    </h1>
    <p className="text-[#9E9E9E] text-base md:text-lg mb-6 md:mb-8 text-center px-4 md:px-0 max-w-xs md:max-w-lg">
        Dive deep and get hooked on exclusive case studies, strategies, and insights tailored specifically to grow your SaaS product.
    </p>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="flex flex-col w-full space-y-3 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-4 md:flex-row max-w-md">
    <input 
    name="email"
    type="email"
    placeholder="Your Email"
    className={`flex-grow text-sm bg-[#383838] text-white placeholder-[#646363] py-1 md:py-2 px-3 md:px-4 rounded-l-lg md:rounded-none focus:border-[#FFC107] border-2 ${errors?.email ? 'border-red-500' : ''} border-transparent focus:outline-none`}
    {...register("email",{
        required: "Email is required.",
        pattern: {
            value: /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/,
            message: "Please enter a valid email"
        }
    })}
    style={{borderRadius: '10px'}}
/>
{errors?.email?.message && <p className="text-red-500 mt-1">{errors.email.message}</p>}
        {serverMessage && <p className={serverMessage.includes('Thanks') ? "text-green-500 mt-1" : "text-red-500 mt-1"}>{serverMessage}</p>}
        
        <button className="text-sm bg-[#FFC107] text-black px-6 py-1 md:py-2 w-full md:w-auto rounded-r-lg" 
            type="submit"
            disabled={formState.isSubmitting}
            style={{borderRadius: '10px'}}
        >
            {formState.isSubmitting ? 'Processing...' : 'Join Now'}
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
 
    )
}
```

The above file is the jsx file and I'm next js 13 with app layout, the route file is in app/api/subscribe/route.js there is no mistake there. The only mistake the post method.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).end();
  }

  const { email } = req.body;
  if (!email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email is required' });
  }

  try {
    // Replace YOUR_API_SECRET and YOUR_FORM_ID with your ConvertKit values
    const API_KEY = 'API_KEY';
    const FORM_ID = 'API_FORM_ID';
    const CONVERTKIT_ENDPOINT = `https://api.convertkit.com/v3/forms/${FORM_ID}/subscribe`;

    const response = await axios.post(CONVERTKIT_ENDPOINT, {
      api_key: API_KEY,
      email,
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    });

    // Check if there's any error in ConvertKit's response
    if (response.data.error) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: response.data.error.message });
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ success: true });

  } catch (error) {
    // Check for errors in the response (if any)
    if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: error.response.data.error.message });
    }
    
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while subscribing. Please try again.' });
  }
}
```

I've hidden the API key and post id.